# Determine which button called an actionPerformed method

Tags: java, user-interface

I am making a maze program in Java which consists of a grid of MazeButtons which extend JButton and have a field for State (which is the location of the button and some other information about how the maze should work). Another class, MazeFrame, extends JFrame and implements ActionListener. When I construct the GUI in the setup class, I add the MazeFrame ActionListener to each button. I want the actionPerformed method in MazeFrame to be able to check to see if the action the user attempted is allowed, but in order to do that I need to know which button was clicked.

How can you know which button called a given actionPerformed method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the getSource method on the event and it will return the object that fired it

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, new to the site.